# maintaining a list of users - MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, list

I have a table `memberships`.

I supply my user with a text box, in which there is a list of the current emails in `memberships`. They can edit the list. Once they send the list back, I want to update memberships so it *only* contain emails that are in the list the user supplied.

The best way I can think of is just to delete all emails and just insert the whole list back in. Is there a better method?

What I am doing now:

```
  $mysql->query('DELETE FROM memberships');

  $userEmails = explode('\n', $_POST['users']);
  foreach ($userEmails as $email)
    $mysql->query('INSERT INTO memberships (email) VALUES (?)', $email);
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: From usability point of view the best way of doing this will be providing user a list of associated emails with 'x' button against each, which will make an ajax request to remove this email. And the field below this list to add new one.

Comment: I have some ideas (including what kenota said), but in order to do what you ultimately want (editable text field with all the emails dumbed in it) I think you'll need to empty your table every time. However, I highly recommend what kenota said.

Comment: You'll want to `explode` by `"\n"`, not `'\n'`, unless you literally have the characters *\n* in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe are what you are looking for (untested). Dont forget to escape your input before using in querys to prevent sql injections.

```
$userEmails = explode("\n", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['users']));
$mysql->query("DELETE FROM `memberships` WHERE `email` NOT IN ('".implode("','", array_values($userEmails))."');");
$mysql->query("REPLACE INTO `memberships` (`email`) VALUES ('".implode("'),('", array_values($userEmails)).");");
```

Comment: but then again he/she needs to insert the new emails

Comment: and if you can change '\n' to "\n"

Answer (score 2):

@BloodyWorld just submitted a better MySQL-based solution as I was typing this, but I'm submitting this anyway!

You could try this solution:

```
// Pull the current list of emails from the database
$current_emails = $mysql->query('SELECT email FROM memberships');
$user_emails = explode('\n', $_POST['users']);

// This array will contain only the emails to add
$new_emails = array_diff($user_emails, $current_emails);  

// This array will contain only the emails to delete
$deleted_emails = array_diff($current_emails, $user_emails);

// Add the new ones
foreach ($new_emails as $email)
  $mysql->query('INSERT INTO memberships (email) VALUES (?)', $email);

// Delete the old ones
$mysql->query("DELETE FROM memberships WHERE email NOT IN('".implode("','", $deleted_emails)."')");
```

It involves more code, but it removes the possibility of all of your members getting deleted from the database before it gets a chance to loop through and parse the submitted text. You also end up with an array of "new" and "old" members, which might be handy for some other purpose here.